# I want to create a scrolling list like the one in the picture. Can someone help me

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, user-interface

I'm trying to make a list like TimePicker like in the picture. Can someone help me

[image]

Comment: Try finding a 3rd-party library for that. I am sure you will find one.

Answer (score 1):

Try customizing with the help of this library ,found in [Github](https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker).

Add this to your xml file

```
<com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker
 android:id="@+id/number_picker"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
 app:np_width="64dp"
 app:np_height="180dp"
 app:np_dividerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
 app:np_formatter="@string/number_picker_formatter"
 app:np_max="59"
 app:np_min="0"
 app:np_selectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
 app:np_selectedTextSize="@dimen/selected_text_size"
 app:np_textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
 app:np_textSize="@dimen/text_size"
 app:np_typeface="@string/roboto_light"
 app:np_value="3" />
```

Add this to your class

```
NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.number_picker);
// set divider color 
numberPicker.setDividerColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
numberPicker.setDividerColorResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
// set formatter
numberPicker.setFormatter(getString(R.string.number_picker_formatter));
numberPicker.setFormatter(R.string.number_picker_formatter);
// set selected text color 
numberPicker.setSelectedTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
numberPicker.setSelectedTextColorResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
// set text color 
numberPicker.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.dark_grey));
numberPicker.setTextColorResource(R.color.dark_grey);
// set text size 
numberPicker.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size));
numberPicker.setTextSize(R.dimen.text_size);
// set selected text size 
numberPicker.setSelectedTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.selected_text_size));
numberPicker.setSelectedTextSize(R.dimen.selected_text_size);
// set typeface 
numberPicker.setTypeface(Typeface.create(getString(R.string.roboto_light), Typeface.NORMAL));
numberPicker.setTypeface(getString(R.string.roboto_light), Typeface.NORMAL);
numberPicker.setTypeface(getString(R.string.roboto_light));
numberPicker.setTypeface(R.string.roboto_light, Typeface.NORMAL);
numberPicker.setTypeface(R.string.roboto_light);
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [this](https://androidrepo.com/repo/ty0x2333-WheelPicker-android-media-picker) library it does the exact same thing.